# Help to understand the use of "such as" in "A hatred such as he had never known before..."

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> A hatred **such as** he had never known before was coursing through Harry like poison.

As I know, the phrase "*such as*" can mean "*for example*" or '*like*' and is followed by a list or a noun, pronoun and etc. But in this sentence, it's followed by a clause. It looks to me that it's like saying: *A hatred **that** he had never known before was coursing through Harry like poison*. It seems to function as "**that**" in this case.

How should we understand it in this sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means "like" here as well, more or less.  A wooden paraphrase would be **of a kind that** he had never known.

**as** is a clause subordinator.

You hear contemporary speakers asking "Such as?" when they want to elicit examples from the person they're speaking with, and so it's easy to think that those words belong together, but if you were to parse that sentence in slo-mo it would be:

> A .. hatred .. such ..... as he had never known.

Comment: Is it common?  I've never seen it's used like that before.

Comment: It was more common in the 18th, 19th, and early 20th centuries than it is now; you won't *hear* it much, but you will encounter it in plenty of books. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22such%20as%20he%20had%20never%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: What part of speech is 'such'? *Pronoun* or *adverb*?

Comment: I don't believe in parts of speech. They're just labels for *in situ* function. Here, *such* means "of a kind".

Comment: It's somewhat more formal, so I agree with @Tᴚoɯɐuo that you wouldn't typically hear it spoken aloud as in this example.  It is seen more often in literature.

Comment: Can we use "that" to replace 'as': *A hatred such **that** he had never known before ...*?

Comment: No, **that** cannot be substituted for **as** here.

Comment: @dan "like" would be a more appropriate substitution here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the pattern: A [noun] + such as [subject] had never [known, experienced, seen, etc.] is common in English writing.

- Wealth such as the country had never seen etc.
- Destruction such as the state had never experienced etc.
- Love such as he had never known etc.
- Good fortune such as they had never had etc.

This pattern is often seen in formal and literary writing.

Consider this:

A decision //such as this// was unusual.
such as this= like the one.

A decision //such as the one he was making// was unusual.
such as the one he was making=like the one he was making

In writing, "such as" would be preferred to "like", as strictly speaking, like is for similes (He looks like a rat.) and such as is for providing an example that stands out. (A man such as he had never run for office.)

**such as** can be followed by a noun or a clause.

Answer (score 2):

"A hatred **that** he had never known before" is quite specific.   There is only one hatred in that phrasing.    "A hatred **such as** he had never known before" has a broader meaning.   Not only has he never known *this* hatred, but he has never known any other hatred *like* it.   That meaning which "such as" shares with "for example" and "like" hasn't been lost.

The word "such" is an adjective.   On its own it usually occurs as a premodifier, as in "such hatred" or "such a hatred".   Here it takes a natural (but optional) post-positive position because it is directly modified by the following prepositional phrase.

The word "as" is a preposition.   However, the clause that serves as its argument is not an object.   Rather, it is a complement.   Here it serves as the postcedent of the anaphoric adjective "such".

We should take the subject of this sentence to mean *a hatred of a kind that he had never known before*, probably *a hatred of a greater strength than he had ever known before*.